# Exchange 2007: Add email address from another domain to one user

Tags: exchange, domain, exchange-2007

I want to add the email address `office@new-domain.com` to only one of our users. This is an additional domain and has nothing to do with the existing domain. I set up the MX records accordingly (pointing to our Exchange 2007 server). Now the server has to accept emails from this domain.

[From this article](http://www.petri.co.il/configure-exchange-2007-recieve-email-other-domains.htm) I found out that I can add an `accepted domain`  under `hub transport`. The user which should receive the mails from office@new-domain.com has already an existing email account. Normally, I add an mail alias to the user easily. This is what I have don yet but only users in the domain can send mails to office@new-domain.com now. If I add the accepted domain all users in the domain will get mails from `forename.surename@new-domain.com` I think.

What is the best solution for me? Can I add an email account from another domain to only one existing user account and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your users will not receive the new email addresses unless you modify your **Email Address Policy** to include it.  Just add the new accepted domain and then modify the individual user that you wish to have the new address.